# Custom theme for Media Volume Controller (whatever it's called) of Android?

Tags: android, media, volume

I'm trying custom the theme of Media Volume Controller (I don't know what it's called, just try to name it). It's something like a Toast with "Media Volume" title which appears when we press volume buttons (+ and -) in games. But I don't know which View it's, or it's a Toast, a Dialog. So far as I try, I could not find anything which refers it. Only **Activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)**
to enable it in your Activity, and nothing more. If someone know how to custom it, or just it's name, please help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for my misunderstanding of your question.

I think the way you can customize "Media Volume Controller" is control volume yourself and show your customize view(or Toast). Because the "Media Volume" Toast(It is a Toast, see the source code of [VolumePanel.onShowVolumeChanged](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/view/VolumePanel.java;h=e21824e0647daf41c0663980f171888f69dd527a;hb=HEAD) ) is created and shown by android system which you cannot customize.

Here is the sample code which might solve your problem:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        // Or use adjustStreamVolume method.
        am.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        // Or use adjustStreamVolume method.
        am.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thank again for your help. I'll try your suggestion. Really sorry I'm newcomer on Stackflow so I cannot vote for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onKeyDown` of your game Activity. And show the "Toast" according to the key just pressed. `onKeyDown` method will be called when a key was pressed down in your Activity. Following is sample code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        // show volumn up toast
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        // show volumn down toast
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I also thought about it, but that Media Volume Controller is not Toast, because if it is displaying and you press volume button, it'll not re-appear but change the volume bar (a Toast'll disappear then re-appear after few seconds). And it is placed at the top of screen, not the bottom like Toast. Arghh, I wish I knew what class does it belong >_<

Comment: Anh Tuan, I think it actually is a Toast. Have a look at the Toast API. There are possibilities to set a custom view for the Toast and you can change the Toast's content while it's showing and you also can change the position of the Toast using the setGravity() method.